# Permission Problem when PHP POST'ing multipart/form-data from Obj-C to new server

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, permissions, multipartform-data

So I feel like there is probably a very easy answer for this, something that I am overlooking but I can not figure it out.

Im developing an iPhone app for someone.  Up until yesterday I was testing it all on my server and everthing was running fine.  Yesterday I started to migrate all the files over and when I did my image upload scripts no longer work.

The code im using on the iPhone side is this

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 90);

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@File.php", MENUURL];
NSLog(@"URL STRING: %@", urlString);

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", id] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];    

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

NSLog(@"RS: %@", returnString);
```

Then when I get to logging the returnString Im presented with this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /Directory/Directory/File.php
on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

Meanwhile the file does have correct permissions, same as it did on my server.  If I go to the file through a web browser or send it a POST request of type

```
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

it allows me to access the file (although it returns an error since the necessary data wasnt provided)

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?  Ive been searching all morning and unable to find anything really useful

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: You need to grant the webserver permissions on the directories as well. There's no point in putting a "free, take one" box inside a bank vault - the flyer's free, but you can't get into the vault to get one in the first place.

Comment: Im sorry and that is done how?  Because all directors from top down that I'm using have the correct and same permissions as they did when on my server

Comment: Anyone have any clue? This only happens when I try to do multipart/form data POST actions to my server from the iphone app.  Any other connections work fine